# Does "order_cancel_after" always work?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, event-observer

I have created a custom module that executes a function when an order is canceled. I am using `order_cancel_after` event to do this and it works most of the times, but not always.

There's a payment extension, which code is encrypted. When an order is canceled by this payment extension, the `order_cancel_after` event function is not executed.
Possible ways that the order is canceled are the following:

```
$order->registerCancellation();

$order->cancel()->save();

$order->setStatus(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)->addStatusHistoryComment($orderComment)->save();
```

Is there any other event I could use? Is `order_cancel_after` a safe way to track order cancelation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rather observer event `sales_order_save_after` and check for

```
if ($observer->getOrder()->isCanceled()) {
           //Your code 
        }
```